# Mysql Loop By Query Result

Tags: mysql

I have this query that produces a list of foreign keys:

```
SELECT ad_id 
FROM ads AS i
INNER JOIN ads_earnings AS e
ON i.ad_id = e.earning_ad_id
GROUP BY i.ad_id
```

I want to use that as the parameter for this query in a loop:

```
INSERT INTO ads_stats_traffic
(traffic_ad_id,traffic_country_id,traffic_paid,traffic_verified,traffic_total) 
(
    SELECT earning_ad_id, earning_country_id, earning_paid, SUM(earning_verified), COUNT(earning_id)
    FROM ads_earnings
    WHERE earning_ad_id = ?
    GROUP BY earning_paid, earning_country_id
)
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a nested subquery with `in` should work:

```
INSERT INTO ads_stats_traffic
(traffic_ad_id,traffic_country_id,traffic_paid,traffic_verified,traffic_total) 
(
    SELECT earning_ad_id, earning_country_id, earning_paid, SUM(earning_verified), COUNT(earning_id)
    FROM ads_earnings
    WHERE earning_ad_id in
    (
        SELECT ad_id 
        FROM ads AS i
        INNER JOIN ads_earnings AS e
        ON i.ad_id = e.earning_ad_id
        GROUP BY i.ad_id
    )
    GROUP BY earning_paid, earning_country_id
)
```

Comment: Ohhhhh IN.....new SQL word for me......Just going to take my dog walkies and then I try it out :)